# Is this a sufficient proof for $ x-ε<a≤x$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

The problem is:

> If $y=Sup(S)$, show that, for each $ε>0$, there is $a \in S$ such that $x-ε  \lt a \le x$.

Proof:

Suppose $x=Sup(S)$. Let $S=\{\text{n: n is a real number and } n\le x\}$. Consider $x-ε$, where $ε\gt0$. Since $x-ε$ is clearly not the least upper bound of $S$, it follows that $x-ε  \lt x$. Furthermore, because $x-ε$ is not the least upper bound, then there must be some $a \in S$ such that $x-ε \lt a$ and $a \le x.$ Therefore, $x-ε \lt a \le x.$

I am not sure if I am right or not. I appreciate any suggestions for clarification or improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include that $\sup S < \infty$. Otherwise subtraction doesn't make sense.

Comment: After including that, is the proof fine? Thanks.

Comment: @user328649 Yes the proof is fine. You might want to reference the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ when justifying the existence of $a$.